# Angular generator for large application

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator

Is there an Angular example app or Yeoman generator out there that would satisfy the following needs?

- Usage of nested routing
- Lazy loading of modules
- (Optional) Usage of gulp instead of grunt

I'm mostly concerned about setting up module loading properly, so that I don't have to init all controllers at the start of the application.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a yeoman generator that will cater for your requirements. I think a safe bet would be to scaffold yourself; you can also make it super clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.dancancro.com/comparison-of-angularjs-application-starters) is a detailed comparison of the ones I've studied.

These have nested routing (ui-router):

- generator- ng-poly
- MeanJS.org.
- generator- angular- fullstack
- MEAN.io.
- forms-angular
- Joe Eames's Course (10/13)
- ngbp (ng-boilerplate)
- Deborah Kurata's Course
- Gocardless's Way
- generator- angular-xl
- Alexander Zanfir's Course
- generator- ng-appgen
- wrapbootstrap Angle template
- radian.io.
- generator- cg-angular
- generator- ngbp
- generator-ghurt
- Steve Michelotti's Course
- Nathan Cox's Way
- Breeze Zza sample

This has lazy loading of modules:

- wrapbootstrap Angle template

These use Gulp:

- CleverStack
- generator- ng-poly
- MeanJS.org.
- generator- bangular
- generator- jhipster
- MEAN.io.
- wrapbootstrap Angle template
- John Papa's gulp-patterns repo (9/14)
- generator- gulp- angular
- John Papa's Clean Code Course (10/14)
- Jeff Dickey's Course
- angular-gulp- browserify-livereload- boilerplate
- generator- gulp- webapp
- angular-kickstart